# Creating a ConTeXt/LaTeX hybrid module

Tags: context, package-writing, modules

I have a simple titlepage, which I want to make available for ConTeXt- as well as LaTeX users. Each should just type `\usemodule[myTitlepage]`, or `\usepackage{myTitlepage}`, respectively.

I want to do this by determining if LaTeX is used, and if so, define all used ConTeXt-macros to their LaTeX equivalents, so that the titlepage can be written in ConTeXt, similar to this:

```
\ifLaTeX
    \newcommand{\starttikzpicture}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]}
    \newcommand{\stopttikzpicture}   {\end  {tikzpicture}    }
    \newcommand{\crlf}{\\}
    ...
\else
    \doConTeXtRelatedStuff
\fi

\starttikzpicture[scale=3]
    \node [text centered] {it works! \crlf or does it?};
\stoptikzpicture
```

What do I use instead of the pseudocode `\ifLaTeX` and will the whole idea likely work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check for some macros that is defined only in LaTeX or ConTeXt. For example, ConTeXt defines `\contextformat` and `\contextversion` which hopefully should not be defined by a LaTeX package. Similarly LaTeX defines `\documentclass` which is not defined by any ConTeXt module.

However, a better solution might be to let `kpse` choose the format for you. Create a file called `mytitlepage.tex` in `$TEXMF/tex/genereic/....` that contains the common code. Then create a file `mytitlepage.sty` in `$TEXMF/tex/latex/...` that contains latex specific code and loads `mytitlepage.tex` and create a file `t-mytitlepage.(tex|mkii|mkiv|lua)` in `$TEXMF/tex/context/third/...` that contains ConTeXt specific code and loads `mytitlepage.tex`. This way, the right file is chosen depending on the format.

Comment: That's the approach `pgf` takes: I'd been meaning to post something very similar :-)

Comment: That seems to be a very standard-compliant way of doing it, but it means that I have to develop an install script that puts the files into the user’s texmf tree, instead of simply telling them to drop a single `.tex` file next to their document in order to install it. But then, I could as well just let the script generate the appropriate file: `./make_titlepage.py latex`. A “drop-in” module would be best.

Comment: @flying sheep: If you want the user to put the package in a local tree, you can just distribute the three files together (in the user directory). If you are asking the user to install on the texmf tree, you can distribute a zip file which has the right TDS structure. You need such a zip file any ways if you upload to CTAN or if you want your users to be able to install the package through texlive or miktex.